# Grant access to google calendar to all users

Tags: google-calendar-api

Using the google calendar API, can I make one user's single calendar event visible to all other users who visit their page or account?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the docs it's right here https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the `Access Control List` of a resource

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl

Specifically the `scope.type` property.

To one of the following

```
"default" - The public scope. This is the default value.
"user" - Limits the scope to a single user.
"group" - Limits the scope to a group.
"domain" - Limits the scope to a domain.
```

and then the `scope.value` -    The email address of a user or group, or the name of a domain, depending on the scope type. Omitted for type "default".

an [example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/update) would be

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/acl/ruleId
```

[read more here](http://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing)

Comment: Thank you. Last question. I'm still reading documentation and I want to know if it's possible to show only events on the calendar of a certain type. So, if my program is for dog walkers, of course the only relevant events on their calendar are when they can walk dogs, not when they are scheduled to see their friends or other personal calendar items. OR, is the answer to this having the user create a secondary calendar for only pertinent events?